# How to delete all records in table without condition using knex?

Tags: javascript, mysql, knex.js

Question is kinda simple. I want to delete all rows from my table using knex, but without conditions.

```
await knex('my_table')
  .del().where()
```

Method `.del()` uses condition. Is it possible? Or is there any SQL syntax to do that?

Comment: just write ```await knex('my_table').del();```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it's really easy, just add condition, which always will be true:

```
await knex('my_table')
  .del().where('id', '!=', 'null')
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to delete all rows, you just need to use `.del()` without any `where` condition.

```
await knex('my_table').del()
```

Note that it will not delete the table. It will delete all the rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

I think what are you looking for is `truncate()`. It does exactly what you've asked for:

```
await knex('table_name').truncate()
```